# Just brought a snake plant from the store and

Tags: houseplants, snake-plants

I just wanna know how I can fix it? Like the edges are brown ...
I cannot upload a photo ... it's too big sadly. I am a beginner to plants. I ordered it thru instacart.

Comment: A quick and dirty way to reduce image size is to paste the image in MS Paint and choosing save as > JPEG. That should reduce the size significantly, even if the image already was a .jpg file. Might get you below the 2MB threshold. I doubt anybody will be able to help you with just this little information _and_ without an image.

Comment: Brown edges on leaves is most likely a sign of overwatering. How is the drainage of your soil? Do you let the soil dry up between waterings?

Comment: I've heard that many houseplants (at least in big box stores) this time of the year have dry/brown parts. There's a good possibility that they grow them in greenhouses that get too hot/sunny for them in the summer. You're much less likely to replicate those conditions in your own home, though.